# Help with an apparently simple proof in complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

If $w=f(z)$ is a complex analytic function. I have been asked to proof that $$\frac{dw}{dz}=e^{-i\theta}\cdot\frac{\partial w}{\partial r}$$
Any hint? My main problem is the partial derivative on the right side of the equal sign. What am I supposed to do? $w=re^{i\theta}$ is not working because $$\frac{\partial w}{\partial r}=e^{i\theta}$$ and is it getting quite 'Kleiny'.

Comment: Could you paraphrase your question? It seems something is missing.

Comment: @Marc Isn't there missing a minus sign? Shouldn't it be $\;e^{-i\theta}\;$ on the right hand side?

Comment: @Timbuc, of course, I'm sorry, edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a minus sign missing in that equality the problem is solved at once:

Put $\;z=re^{i\theta}\;$ , so $\;w=f(re^{i\theta})\;$ , and then

$$e^{-i\theta}\frac{\partial w}{\partial r}=e^{-i\theta}\frac{dw}{dz}\frac{dz}{dr}=e^{-i\theta}\frac{dw}{dz}e^{i\theta}=\frac{dw}{dz}$$

Comment: It was quite simple in fact, thank you!